# Google Sheets: Overwrite Error using ARRAYFORMULA + VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm using VLOOKUP with ARRAYFORMULA to add new data to rows in an existing workbook based on ID numbers. The data is coming from a separate tab. I can get this to work if the column that contains the field i'm importing is completely blank, but if there is existing data I get an overwrite error.

I want the formula to update if the cell is blank, ignore existing data, and display nothing if my "import" has no value and there is no existing value present either.

```
=(ARRAYFORMULA((IFERROR(IF(LEN(A2:A), VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet2!A2:B, 2, 0), )))))
```

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17k25gz0fi0BdJ06eqXIprIpHHF42jLe66PhGFHtzP_k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you cant do that. you will need one mor column a put that array threre and them one more column which will construct your array from these two last columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**F2:** **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), IF(D2:D<>"", D2:D, E2:E), ))`**

**E2: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(LEN(A2:A), VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet2!A2:B, 2, 0), )))`**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful. You just used 
     =CONCAT(D2:E2) in F2 to merge the two, right?

Comment: @LandonC `CONCAT(D2:E2)` was not used. I used simple `IF` in combination with `ARRAYFORMULA`